# Increase Java HeapSpace in Zipkin Docker Container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, zipkin

I am using a docker command to run zipkin and increase the heap space.
The command I am using is:

```
docker run \
-e JAVA_OPTS="Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError" \
--name zipkin -p 2005:9411 -d openzipkin/zipkin:latest
```

The output is :

```
17b2f1a0e8bf5129a527318f01463ea16f3aef8fb4b229f9693bceb17e12ad59
```

This means the image is getting created. But the error appears on log:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Xms1g**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Xms1g**

How to resolve. Please help.

> I am using MacOS with m1 chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your command.

This one works OK.

```
docker run \
-e JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError" \
--name zipkin -p 2005:9411 -d openzipkin/zipkin:latest
```

You need to add an `-` before *Xms1g*